# What are "correlation time" and "relaxation time" in oscillations?

Tags: oscillators, coupled-oscillators

I am reading [this](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v102/i19/e194102) paper which is about oscillations. I came across two terms called "Correlation time" and "Relaxation time" in the following passages:

> In this Letter, we solve these problems by formulating the
>   stochastic phase reduction with careful consideration of the
>   relationship between the correlation time of the noise and relaxation
>   time of the amplitude of the limit cycle.
>
> Noise in the real world has a small but finite correlation time [17]. When the correlation time is much smaller than characteristic
>   time scales of the noise-driven system, we can use the white noise
>   description by taking the limit where the correlation time goes to
>   zero.

I took a look to the book, [Synchronization by Pikovsky et. al.](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/nonlinear-science-and-fluid-dynamics/synchronization-universal-concept-nonlinear-sciences?format=PB), but there, it also starts talking about these terms for the first time in section 3.6.3 and without defining the terms. Can somebody help me with this definitions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it is trying to say is that white noise is uncorrelated (truly random, implying a zero correlation time) while real noise is not actually random and has a pattern to it that repeats in finite time. So the correlation time it is referring to is the amount of time for the signal to "repeat" in a statistical sense.

I don't see a relaxation time in the quote you put in your question. But a relaxation time is usually the amount of time it takes for a non-equilibrium effect to reach equilibrium (for example, the time it takes for initial disturbances to die out in a vibrating system leaving only the forced response, or the amount of time it would take for energy to move between modes in a gas dynamics context). What it is likely talking about is if the amount of time it takes for the system's response to noise in real life is longer than the correlation time of the real life noise, you can use white noise as a good enough approximation to the real signal.

**Update:**

In response to the comment looking for a more mathematical definition... I think there are probably many definitions that could be used and give the same intuitive sense but the one I would choose for a "correlation time" is the length of time it would take for the [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) of the signal to be zero. If you have a signal $X(t)$ and you compute the correlation of the signal with itself at another time, ie. $X(t+\tau)$ then $\tau$ is the correlation time. For a truly random signal (white noise), $\tau = 0$ because that's when the autocorrelation is zero. It's uncorrelated from the start.

But real noise will have some finite $\tau$ where the autocorrelation is not zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. I update the question and sorry that I forgot about relaxation time. Still I don't get what is "statistical sense". I mean I can get an intuition but I am coming from a mathematical background. Is there any definition for this term at all?

Comment: @Naji I added a more precise definition, at least the one I would use. But there's likely multiple possible definitions that give the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

An oscillator is always noisy, it has both amplitude and phase fluctuation. This fluctuation, in general, is not independent from one instant to the next. In a good oscillator the amplitude fluctuation is usually much less than that of the phase. You can observe this noise either in time domain on an oscilloscope, or in frequency domain on a spectrum analyzer. If you connect one to a spectrum analyzer you will not see a pure tone, an infinitely narrow spike, but instead it will have some spectral width that is mush less than the nominal frequency of oscillation; in the case of a quartz oscillator the ratio may be 1 to $10^5$. The reciprocal of the "3dB spectral width" shown on the spectrum analyzer, i.e., the half power width, gives an order of magnitude indication of the time it takes for the oscillation phase to wander sufficiently far away so that the noise riding on the phase samples measured this much time apart are effectively uncorrelated, and if are normally distributed then are stochastically independent, as well. (Intuitively, you can think of the spectral width as the result of an internal filtering of similar bandwidth. Note, too that if you take pure normal (thermal) noise and pass it through a narrow band-pass filter, the noise samples at the output are uncorrelated when taken at instances separated by the reciprocal bandwidth.)